# How can I add a footer view to NSTableView?

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

It seems that `NSTableView` has no equivalent to `UITableView`'s `tableFooterView` property. What is the preferred way to add a footer view to a table view in Cocoa?

Answer (score 4):

NSTableView doesn't have sections like UITableView or NSCollectionView, and therefore no headers and footers.

Instead you can do it via your datasource, if you are using a view-based table.

1. Add a cell to your table in Interface Builder with custom styling/elements that you need in your footer. Give it an identifier like "TableFooter"
2. Increment (by one) the number of rows returned by your NSTableViewDataSource's `numberOfRowsInTableView(tableView:)`
3. and in `tableView(tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:)` for this last row, instantiate that item from storyboard using the identifier "TableFooter".

Comment: did this help you further, @Christoffer?