# Is there a way to add a footer view to NSTableView?

Tags: macos, cocoa, footer, nstableview

I need to add a view very similar to a table footer view in iOS, but to `NSTableView`. Is there a painless way to do it?

Many thanks!

Comment: There is no painless way to do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add a footer view to NSTableView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13892938/how-can-i-add-a-footer-view-to-nstableview)